# Ошибка при присваивании значения элементу массива из объектов класса на Java

Tags: java, массивы

Пытаюсь создать массив из объектов класса. При присваивании нулевого элемента происходит ошибка.

Место, где происходит ошибка

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class food extends AppCompatActivity {

    product[] foodList = new product[3];

    foodList[0] = new product("Name", 1 , 2, 3, 4); // Ошибка здесь

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);



    }
}
```

Сам класс

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class product
{
    public String name;
    public int calories;
    public int proteins;
    public int fats;
    public int carbs;

    public product(String name, int calories, int proteins, int fats, int carbs) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.proteins = proteins;
        this.fats = fats;
        this.carbs = carbs;
    }
}
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: код написали, а в функцию, куда код положить - забыли.

Comment: Действительно, глупая ошибка. Спасибо)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Данный код `foodList[0] = new product("Name", 1 , 2, 3, 4);` должен находиться внутри метода, либо блока инициализации, что и сказано в ошибке.

Java - объектно-ориентированный язык, что означает, что взаимодействие с объектами должно производиться внутри каких-либо методов.

Лучшим решением будет создать метод с установлением первого продукта либо добавлением продукта, и после вызывать его.

Также Вы можете использовать блоки инициализации такие как:

```
{
    foodList[0] = new product("Name", 1, 2, 3, 4);
};
```

Данный блок будет вызван перед конструктором класса и проинициализирует первый элемент массива этим объектом класса `product`.

Пара небольших советов в написании программ на языке Java:

- В данном языке есть свой [Code Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) - договоренность разработчиков о том как должен выглядеть код, следовательно названия классов должны начинаться с заглавной буквы
- Использование статических массивов ведет к появлению многих проблем (как например выход за границы массива), сейчас разумнее использовать динамические массивы, такие как List (ArrayList), вместо обычных массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ясно с чем ошибка, скорей всего некорректно инициализируется значение первого элемента массива.

- Корректная инициализация массива сразу же при определении (число элементов указывать нельзя):

```java
    product[] foodList = {
        new product("Name", 1, 2, 3, 4),
        null,
        null
    };
```

- С использованием блока инициализации:

```java
    product[] foodList = new product[3];

    {
        foodList[0] = new product("Name", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    };
```